# Django SlugField versus URLField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Both of these fields appear to serve essentially the same purpose.  Are there any situations in which you would choose a SlugField instead of a URLField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URLField` is used to store URL, where as `SlugField` is used to store a alphanumeric/varchar value that relates to the title or some description of the model.

**Example**

URL: `https://www.example.com/products/whss1540-wrogn-printed-slim-fit-sweatshirt`

Slug: `whss1540-wrogn-printed-slim-fit-sweatshirt`